# Acces iPhone 6 barometer in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to retrieve data from the iPhone 6 barometer using JavaScript? I can only find native solutions on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

If you use javascript in a web browser it is not possible but you can do that if you using library that give you javascript API to the device like [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you have any source for this?

Comment: Sure, you can start by check the Apache Cordova home page http://cordova.apache.org/ (PhoneGap is a distribution of Apache Cordova) and  also check the "cordova-plugin-barometer" http://plugreg.com/plugin/zanderso/cordova-plugin-barometer